# Spring LDAP and MemberOf

Tags: java, spring, ldap, spring-ldap

I m actually building an application that deals with a LDAP using Spring (http://projects.spring.io/spring-ldap/)

I m having some trouble when trying to modify the memberOf property.

In fact, when I modify my user without modifying the memberOf property, the modification is well taken in care.

When I try to modify my memberOf property using a List(String) with :

```
CN=Administrateurs,CN=Builtin,DC=<dc>,DC=<dc>
CN=Utilisateurs,CN=Builtin,DC=<dc>,DC=<dc>
```

, I got something like this error :

```
javax.naming.OperationNotSupportedException : Error while updating user XXX YYY - matricule AAAAAAA: [LDAP: error code 53 - 0000209A: SvcErr: DSID-031A10E7, problem 5003 (WILL_NOT_PERFORM), data 0
```

From now :

- I m having root rights on the LDAP
- I m able to modify other properties but not this one
- I send the value at a good format (List(String) with good entry)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `memberOf` property is read-only to you. It is maintained automatically when you add a `roleOccupant` or `uniqueMember` to a group, depending on your schema. So do that.

Comment: Only in that direction (group => user) ? No way to make it work from user to group ?

Comment: Is it really read-only? Because I have read that it is an Operational Attribute that requires more effort to read it.

Comment: @zygimantus Yes it is read-only to you; yes it is an operational attribute; and yes operational attributes aren't returned unless you specially ask for them. Your point?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're not providing any code it's hard to pinpoint the exact problem in your case, however a common problem when working with attributes that represent distinguished names (such as the memberOf attribute) is that you need to take extra care when updating in order to avoid duplicates.

In short, you need to tell Spring LDAP that this particular attribute represents distinguished names, by working with [Name](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/naming/Name.html) instances rather than plain strings.

The problem (and solution) is described in the reference documentation [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ldap/docs/current/reference/#dns-as-attribute-values) (for non-ODM-solutions) and [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ldap/docs/current/reference/#odm-dn-attributes) (for ODM).