# Spring boot LDAP get memberOf in ODM

Tags: spring, spring-boot, ldap

I'm currenly building an application using Spring boot LDAP, but have some problems accessing the 'memberOf' property to determine which groups the users belongs to.

I have seen [Spring LDAP and MemberOf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33277674/spring-ldap-and-memberof) but I am using the ODM to get the user from LDAP, when trying to add the 'memberOf' property I get the following error:

```
org.springframework.ldap.odm.core.impl.MetaDataException: Can't determine destination type for field private java.util.ArrayList nl.quintor.afstudeermanagementtool.entitiy.LdapUser.memberOf in class class nl.quintor.afstudeermanagementtool.entitiy.LdapUser
    at org.springframework.ldap.odm.core.impl.AttributeMetaData.determineFieldType(AttributeMetaData.java:167) ~[spring-ldap-core-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.ldap.odm.core.impl.AttributeMetaData.<init>(AttributeMetaData.java:234) ~[spring-ldap-core-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.ldap.odm.core.impl.ObjectMetaData.<init>(ObjectMetaData.java:132) ~[spring-ldap-core-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.ldap.odm.core.impl.DefaultObjectDirectoryMapper.addManagedClass(DefaultObjectDirectoryMapper.java:151) ~[spring-ldap-core-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.ldap.odm.core.impl.DefaultObjectDirectoryMapper.getEntityData(DefaultObjectDirectoryMapper.java:108) ~[spring-ldap-core-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.ldap.odm.core.impl.DefaultObjectDirectoryMapper.filterFor(DefaultObjectDirectoryMapper.java:468) ~[spring-ldap-core-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.find(LdapTemplate.java:1824) ~[spring-ldap-core-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.findAll(LdapTemplate.java:1806) ~[spring-ldap-core-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.findAll(LdapTemplate.java:1814) ~[spring-ldap-core-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.ldap.repository.support.SimpleLdapRepository.findAll(SimpleLdapRepository.java:183) ~[spring-data-ldap-2.3.9.RELEASE.jar:2.3.9.RELEASE]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.ImplementationInvocationMetadata.invoke(ImplementationInvocationMetadata.java:72) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.9.RELEASE.jar:2.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:382) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.9.RELEASE.jar:2.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:205) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.9.RELEASE.jar:2.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:550) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.9.RELEASE.jar:2.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.14.RELEASE.jar:5.2.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:155) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.9.RELEASE.jar:2.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:130) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.9.RELEASE.jar:2.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.14.RELEASE.jar:5.2.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:95) ~[spring-aop-5.2.14.RELEASE.jar:5.2.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.14.RELEASE.jar:5.2.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.2.14.RELEASE.jar:5.2.14.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy82.findAll(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.2.14.RELEASE.jar:5.2.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198) ~[spring-aop-5.2.14.RELEASE.jar:5.2.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.2.14.RELEASE.jar:5.2.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-tx-5.2.14.RELEASE.jar:5.2.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.14.RELEASE.jar:5.2.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.2.14.RELEASE.jar:5.2.14.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy82.findAll(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at nl.quintor.afstudeermanagementtool.seeders.DatabaseSeeder.seedUserTable(DatabaseSeeder.java:59) ~[classes/:na]
    at nl.quintor.afstudeermanagementtool.seeders.DatabaseSeeder.seed(DatabaseSeeder.java:39) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.doInvoke(ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.java:305) ~[spring-context-5.2.14.RELEASE.jar:5.2.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.processEvent(ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.java:190) ~[spring-context-5.2.14.RELEASE.jar:5.2.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.onApplicationEvent(ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.java:153) ~[spring-context-5.2.14.RELEASE.jar:5.2.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172) ~[spring-context-5.2.14.RELEASE.jar:5.2.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165) ~[spring-context-5.2.14.RELEASE.jar:5.2.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139) ~[spring-context-5.2.14.RELEASE.jar:5.2.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:404) ~[spring-context-5.2.14.RELEASE.jar:5.2.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:361) ~[spring-context-5.2.14.RELEASE.jar:5.2.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:898) ~[spring-context-5.2.14.RELEASE.jar:5.2.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:554) ~[spring-context-5.2.14.RELEASE.jar:5.2.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143) ~[spring-boot-2.3.10.RELEASE.jar:2.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:755) ~[spring-boot-2.3.10.RELEASE.jar:2.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) ~[spring-boot-2.3.10.RELEASE.jar:2.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:402) ~[spring-boot-2.3.10.RELEASE.jar:2.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312) ~[spring-boot-2.3.10.RELEASE.jar:2.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1247) ~[spring-boot-2.3.10.RELEASE.jar:2.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1236) ~[spring-boot-2.3.10.RELEASE.jar:2.3.10.RELEASE]
    at nl.quintor.afstudeermanagementtool.AfstudeermanagementtoolApplication.main(AfstudeermanagementtoolApplication.java:16) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.3.10.RELEASE.jar:2.3.10.RELEASE]

2021-05-18 16:14:16.109  INFO 14468 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2021-05-18 16:14:16.112  INFO 14468 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2021-05-18 16:14:16.139  INFO 14468 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.

Process finished with exit code 0
```

The code I'm using is:

```
@Entry(
        objectClasses = { "user, Person", "top", "organizationalPerson" })
public class LdapUser {

    private @Id Name id;

    private @Attribute(name = "cn") String fullName;

    private @Attribute(name = "sAMAccountName") String username;

    private @Attribute(name ="memberof", readonly = true)
    ArrayList<?> memberOf;

    public LdapUser() { }

    public LdapUser(String fullName, String username, ArrayList<?> memberOf) {
        this.fullName = fullName;
        this.username = username;
        this.memberOf = memberOf;
    }

    public String getFullName() {
        return fullName;
    }

    public void setFullName(String fullName) {
        this.fullName = fullName;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public ArrayList<?> getMemberOf() {
        return memberOf;
    }

    public void setMemberOf(ArrayList<?> memberOf) {
        this.memberOf = memberOf;
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried using `ArrayList<String>` for the `memberOf` field ?

Comment: @scottysseus, It failed when I first used List<String>, tried with ? after. On ArrayList<String> it worked, Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a "shortcoming" common to reflection-based object mapping frameworks in Java.

Annotating Java class fields with `@Attribute` only works if the annotated field is a concrete type: that is why the annotation works with `ArrayList<String>` but not `List<String>` or `ArrayList<?>`, because in the latter two cases the object mapper would have to 'guess' which concrete type to use when populating that field. In other words, the object mapper cannot call `new List<String>()`, so it throws an exception.

[You can read about a similar problem](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Advanced_Topics#Interfaces) affecting the JPA ORM standard. JPA appears to have a workaround by providing the [`targetEntity`](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Relationships#Target_Entity) attribute element, but this is only present on some of their annotations (like `@ManyToMany`), and not on `@Column`, which is roughly equivalent to `@Attribute` here.